# Netty binary data not flush out until 0x0a

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, netty

My netty server application needs to reply to the client with binary data, but it seems flush out only when 0x0a is reached.

```
private Logger _log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
private EventLoopGroup _masterGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
private EventLoopGroup _workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
private ByteArrayDecoder _decoder = new ByteArrayDecoder();
private ByteArrayEncoder _encoder = new ByteArrayEncoder();
private Channel _channel;

@PostConstruct
public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    _log.info("component ready");

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .group(_masterGroup, _workerGroup)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline pipe = channel.pipeline();

                    pipe.addLast(_decoder);
                    pipe.addLast(_encoder);
                    pipe.addLast(new ChannelDuplexHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
                            byte[] data = (byte[])msg;
                            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

                            for(byte b : data) {
                                buf.append(String.format("%02x", b)).append(" ");
                            }

                            _log.info(buf.toString());

                            ctx.writeAndFlush(new byte[] { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x0a, 0x36, 0x37 });
                        }
                    });
                }

            });

    _channel = bootstrap.bind(8090).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync().channel();
    _log.info("server readey, listening port: 8090");
}
```

The expected result should be an 8 bytes array, but I got 5 bytes only. So, what is the proper way to send out my buffer?

### edit: add my testing program

```
private String send(byte[] msg) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    String result = null;

    try {
        _log.debug("connecting...");
        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(_ip, _port), 500);
        socket.setKeepAlive(false);

        _log.debug("sending message...");
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write(msg);
        out.flush();

        _log.debug("reading response...");
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        while(null != (result = reader.readLine())) {
            printBuffer("server response", result.getBytes());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        _log.error(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if(null != in) in.close();
            if(null != out) out.close();
            if(null != socket) socket.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            _log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code of _encoder?

Comment: _encoder is declared at the top as ByteArrayEncoder, it's coming from netty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is working correctly, like a test program. But you read response using readLine() method, which reads bytes line by line. The first your line is [0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35], then [0x0a] is the "new line" character, that is not included in result of readLine(). Then a new line [0x36, 0x37], but this line has no end such as "line feed" or "carriage return", so it's also not displayed.

You should rewrite your test program so that it reads and displays the stream of bytes instead of the rows.

Comment: You're right, it's the problem of my testing client program. I just rewrote my test client using ByteArrayOutputStream solve the problem.